# LNK 2019 and LNK1120 errors on a simple c++ sorting program

Tags: c++, sorting, linker

I should preface this by saying that I am an undergrad CS student with little to no knowledge of how compilers work. To me these errors look like complete gibberish, and after scouring the web for about half an hour, I'm afraid I've resigned myself to asking for help =(

here are the errors I'm receiving:

> Prog4Main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl shellSort(struct SortData * const,int)" (?shellSort@@YAXQAUSortData@@H@Z) referenced in function _main
>
> *\Debug\prog4 again.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

These are the only two errors I'm getting.

So, onto what my program is trying to accomplish:

This is a homework assignment in my c++ class. We have to implement 5 of the sorting algorithms shown to us in class. I have implemented bubble sort and insertion sort just fine, but shell sort is giving me these errors. they are in the same .cpp file, and i have no compile errors when i comment out the shellSort() function call.

As it is reaching the end of my summer semester c++ class and we didn't have enough time to cover sort algorithms in depth, the instructor pretty much gave us all code for this program. we just have to change variable names and tweak the form of the sort functions to suit our needs. because of this, I *know* all my code is correct, as I didn't write it.

This is in VS2010 (not express, I think its ultimate), my application is a win32 console application, and I've checked and insured that user32.lib is linked (as it was mentioned in one of the other link error posts). I seriously have no idea how to resolve this problem....

heres the problem code:

```
//---------------------- Begin Shell Sort -----------------------
    totalTime = 0.0; // Initialize the time variable
    sortError = false; // Initialize the error flag
    // For each of 5 runs on this algorithm
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        // Read the data.  You must do this before each sort
        if(!ReadData(DataArray, NUMRECS))
        {
            cout << "Failed to read data file.\n Program Terminated\n";
            return 0;
        }
        // Start the microsecond timer
        mst->Start();

        shellSort(DataArray, NUMRECS);// Call the sort function here PROBLEM SPOT

        // Stop the microsecond timer
        mst->Stop();
        // Check for error in sorting
        if(!CheckData(DataArray, NUMRECS))
            sortError = true;
        else
            totalTime += mst->getTime(); // Add to the total time for this sort
    }
    // Calculate the average time
    averageTime = totalTime / 5.0;

    // Output the results after checking to be sure the sort worked
    if(sortError)
        cout << "Error in Shell Sort\n\n";
    else
        cout << "Shell sort took " << averageTime << " seconds to complete\n\n";
    //------------------------ End Shell Sort -----------------------------
```

Any help you guys can give is much appreciated.

EDIT: heres the prototype and function def...

```
    #define NUMRECS 10000
```

`void shellSort(SortData DataArray[NUMRECS], int count);

int main{...}

//---------------------SHELL SORT------------------------
void ShellSort(SortData DataArray[], int count)
{
    int i, delta;

    delta = count;

    do
    {
        delta = 1 + delta / 3;
        for(i=0; i<delta; i++)
            DeltaInsertionSort(DataArray, i, delta, count);
    }
    while(delta > 1);
}

void DeltaInsertionSort(SortData DataArray[], int I, int Delta, int count)
{
    int            j, k;
    int            key;
    int            NotDone;
    SortData       temp;

    j = I + Delta;

    while(j < count)
    {
        key = DataArray[j].key;        /* Get next key to sort */
        temp = DataArray[j];    /* Remove and hold */

        /* Do insertion sort on this key in the block of delta records */
        /* Move each struct where DataArray[j].key > key to the right  */
        /*   by delta spaces and insert the key there.                 */
        insertion(DataArray, key);

        k = j;
        NotDone = TRUE;

        do
        {
            if(DataArray[k - Delta].key <= key)
                NotDone = FALSE;    /* Terminate the loop */
            else
            {
                DataArray[k] = DataArray[k - Delta];
                k -= Delta;
                if(k==I) NotDone = FALSE;
            }
        }
        while(NotDone);

        /* Insert the moved key */
        DataArray[k] = temp;

        /* Get next key to insert--one full delta increment to the right */
        j += Delta;
    }
}`

Comment: Knowing all your code is correct, but not being the individual to write it is what I would call an Ass-umption by the simplest definition! The errors actually tell you what the problem is! It's saying that a function was referenced, which clearly wasn't defined in the main.cpp scope, and can't seem to resolve external issues. That's why when you comment out the function it works fine!

Comment: You don't have a compiler error it is a linker error. So the linker  cannot find your `shellSort()` function. Is it in a different cpp file, check your project settings if it is included.

Comment: Make sure that the implementation of shellSort is included in the project.

Comment: @mkaes its in the same cpp file. the call is in main, the function is below it.

Comment: @RobertoWilko you know, I agree with you man. except i've been staring at it thinking there may be a problem for the past 30 min. i know, by inspection, that it is correct haha.

Comment: @Nick: can you show us the first line of the `shellSort` function definition (the one with the return type and parameter list), and the declaration of the `shellSort` function which appears in your .cpp file before `main`.

Comment: I tried to migrate from VS to Linux earlier today and was getting all kind of errors! Know what it was? I tried to send "main.cpp" to g++ twice! It wasn't until I was on SO asking what the problem was when I discovered the error myself while copying the makefile on SO, lol!:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ is case-sensitive: `shellSort` vs `ShellSort`. You've declared and called one function, but implemented a completely unrelated function!

The reason this is a linker error rather than a compiler error, is that the forward declaration tells the compiler "there's going to be a definition of this function `shellSort` somewhere", but doesn't specify where. Since it's not in this .cpp file, the compiler takes your word for it that it must be in a different .cpp file that will be linked together with this .cpp file later. When you get to the linking stage, there's still no function `shellSort`.

Comment: Well holy crap. I can't believe that I missed that. You sir, are a lifesaver.

Comment: @Nick: for next time you see this same error -- before you made the edit, the other thing that I thought might have happened is that you declared it with slightly different parameters from what you defined it as, so the definition was of a different overload of `shellSort`, not the overload your call actually calls.